# i still have trouble accepting this

Tags: discussion, bug

i just don't get why my rep should suffer because SE removes some user that, evidently, liked a few of my posts.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is just the way it is... The good thing is if the _user-to-be-deleted_ cast many votes, it would be flagged for staff to review. In which case they might preserve the votes before deleting the account. Unfortunately, it's not possible to do after the fact.

Comment: https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1753/50076

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had a big drop on the same day.!

[image: Graph of reputation also showing a big drop on July 12th.]

Comment: I wonder who the bad user that SE dropped is.