# `stft` tag edit proposal

Tags: discussion, tags

To briefly comment on RBJ's

> The **Short-Time Fourier Transform** (STFT) is an analysis tool that repeatedly applies the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT or FFT) to short snippets of a longer signal, while sliding the window that selects the snippet of the longer signal that the STFT operates on. The STFT is a function of two independent variables, frequency in the DFT and the time of the center of the sliding window.

I think *"repeatedly applies ... operates on"* should stand in its own sentence and  start like "Its standard implementation", and end with "but it can also be done with strided convolutions". That implementation also [lacks a corrective step](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1279#issuecomment-774792464) for some purposes.

"Windowed Fourier transform" is one (and the more common) interpretation, but not the only one - more generally it's a time-frequency decomposition via complex bandpass filters. STFT also isn't exclusively discrete, and even then "frequency *in the DFT*" is too restrictive, even if not going with DFT freqs is a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a suggested form of words? Added a community wiki answer. Feel free to edit.

Comment: @PeterK. Can we follow `dsp.meta` or do you just check?

Comment: I get a notification in a diamond icon in the search bar when meta posts come up. Probably just because I'm a mod.  There seems to be a follow button at the bottom of each question on sites I'm not a mod on.

Comment: Hay, @OverLordGoldDragon, I hadn't seen this post before when it was fresh.  I don't have any problem with mods to any question, answer, or tag that I write as long as the mod is accurate and useful.  I completely understand that some things that I write can be improved.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I've gone through [with an edit](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/83976/revisions), I'm mostly content with it but of course it's open to further discussion.

Comment: Oh, it's not so bad.  the thing about convolving with complex sinusoids or bandpass filtering can just as well be applied to the DFT, or more specifically, Goertzel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempted update:

> The **Short-Time Fourier Transform** (STFT) is an analysis tool that
> repeatedly applies the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT or FFT) to
> short snippets of a longer signal. Its standard implementation slides the
> window along the longer signal selecting the snippet that the STFT operates on.
> The STFT is a function of two independent variables, frequency in the
> DFT and the time of the center of the sliding window.

Feel free to edit!